# MailChimp Campaign Update

Tags: mailchimp

i am trying to use [campaigns/update](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/campaigns/update.php) in MailChimp.
However i still cannot understand how can i use it.
Can anyone please explain to me, for example how can i change the "from_email" parameter?

my current json for that purpose looks like this:

```
{
  "apikey": "my_api_key",
  "cid": "my_campaign_id",
  "name": "options",
  "value": ["list_id_value","subject_value","from_email_value"]
}
```

However when i send this json to campaigns/update, it returns error saying that "Can not update unknown option "2"".

How can i change the json so that i can update the "from_email"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API docs seem to be wrong. Try replacing [ ] with { } and giving field:pair values inside it. So, example to change the subject:

```
{
  "apikey": "my_api_key",
  "cid": "my_campaign_id",
  "name": "options",
  "value": {"subject": "My new subject"}
}
```